# How can open an iphone app from my app in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

How can I open an app from my app in Swift? I need open contacts book to select the contact and save on my app, but I don't know how to do this.. I'm reading how read the contacts and show into a table view but not about how to open the contact book app.  And also I'm reading how to open with UIApplication.sharedApplication() but I only show how to open urls...

There is some form to make this?

Thanks!

Comment: if the targeted app supports URL-scemes, then it is piece of cake (without returning to your app, of course), otherwise you cannot do such thing without risking a possible rejection.

Answer (score 2):

As with what @jtbandes posted, the only way to do this is with URL schemes.  You have no access to launch/read other applications or settings unless your application shares the same bundle identifier as the others (Facebook + Facebook Messenger, for example would share these and be able to detec

Comment: Then I can convert this code to Swift to open facebook: //facebook
if(![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://profile/181239321918026"]])
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.facebook.com/plungeinteractive"]];
}   But what is the url to open the contacts app address books??

Comment: Unfortunately as it stands right now there is no URL scheme for the Contacts application in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Open contacts book is pretty simple. Here a nice tutorial that explain how to do that:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/63885/address-book-tutorial-in-ios

Also: in iOS 8, you can use the inter-app communication extension! It's a really nice feature. You can see that keynote video about this here: http://www.theverge.com/2014/6/2/5765048/apple-wwdc-2014-os-x-yosemite-ios-8-and-all-the-news-you-need-to-know

**EDIT:**

Here is my init method used in my app to present a controller which is the contacts tableView:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [ABPeoplePickerNavigationController new];

        ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();

        picker.addressBook = addressBook;
        picker.displayedProperties = @[[NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonAddressProperty]];
        picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;

        if (addressBook != nil)
            CFRelease(addressBook);

        _controller = picker;
    }
    return self;
}
```

I don't know if this can help you. Anyway, don't forget to use appropriate new methods (not deprecated). I think there are small changes about ABAddressBookCreate();

Comment: This tutorial is approximately that I want make, but I want access to native app contacts, select a contact and show in my app. This is possible. Now I have the code to show all contact in an array, but not show this into native contacts book iphone.. Thanks!!

Comment: I've updated my post. Hope this help you to continue your app ;) If you have any questions, don't hesitate to ask ;)